# First float:left DIV is higher than all the rest in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have 3 divs set to float:left so to appear as 3 columns. Everything looks good in Chrome and FF but explorer is popping the div that is furthest to the left up higher than the other two divs.

This doesn't seem to be a staircase effect because the first div is the only one out of position. The other two divs are on the same line as each other.

Here is the HTML

```
   <div id="home_bows_container">
        <div id="black_bear" class="home_bows">
            <h4>Black Bear</h4>
            <div id="bow_container">
                <a href=""><img alt="custom traditional longbow" src="images/bows_slider/black-bear.png" class="home_bows left"></a>
            </div>
            <h5>Hybrid Reflex/Deflex Longbow<h5>
            <p class="description">62"-66" 25-70 pounds, Black Limbs, Bamboo core, your choice of riser wood.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="prowler" class="home_bows">
            <h4>Prowler</h4>
            <div id="bow_container">
                <a href=""><img alt="custom traditional longbow" src="images/bows_slider/prowler.png" class="home_bows center"></a>
            </div>
            <h5>3 Piece Take Down Reflex/ Deflex Longbow<h5>
            <p class="description">62"-64" 30-70 pound Clear Glass Veneered Limbs, your choice of veneers and riser wood. </p>
        </div>
        <div id="javalina_two" class="home_bows">
            <h4>Javalina II</h4>
            <div id="bow_container">
                <a href=""><img alt="custom 3 piece longbow" src="images/bows_slider/javalina2.png" class="home_bows right"></a>
            </div>
            <h5>Hybrid Reflex/Deflex Longbow<h5>
            <p class="description">62"-66' 30-70 pound Clear Glass Veneered Limbs, your choice of veneers and riser wood.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
    #home_bows_container {
    width:90%;
    min-width:960px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline;
}
.home_bows {
    float:left;
    width:33.33333%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#bow_container {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:102px;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
img.home_bows {
    width:102px;
    height:400px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

I've seen similar questions to mine across the web and the answers have been to add display:block to my container div. But I've tried that to no avail.

Maybe I'm just doing it completely wrong, I don't know. Asking for help is my very last resort. Normally I can find the solution somewhere but I feel like I've tried everything.

If you see this soon enough, you can see what I'm talking about by going here in IE: http://ihacustombows.com/

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I decided just to go with a ul and li setup. Worked out much better. IE does not seem to handle floating divs very well but it knows how to display floating list items just fine.

Thanks for all the help and pointers.

Comment: since #home_bows_container holds the three divs with class home_bows, it should be set to display:block. An inline element should not contain block-level elements, which the three home_bows divs are since they are set to float:left.

Comment: The fact that IE works on the internet at all is a miracle in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Without digging in too deeply, IE sometimes doubles the left margin when an element is floating to the left. Just a thought as to what could be affecting your layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it could be an issue with the way ie rounds the width: 33.333%. Maybe change it to 33% and see if that helps.